# How do I concatenate column data into a single field in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Here's my screenshot: How can I rewrite this query to display a single record but have all four "ColumnName" data fields in a single field?

So basically, I'm after a single row that looks like:

TableName:
20180301_Vitality

ColumnData:
_CustomObjectKey | Email address | Subscriber key | opCoCode 2

[image]

Comment: Google:  SQL Server string aggregation.

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, however I'm running SSMS 2016 and I believe this is a function new to 2017 and newer, unfortunately.  It does however appear to be exactly what I need, but I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server's (2005 or newer) STUFF function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017